# Consulta sql no me trae la info esperada

Tags: sql, laravel, ajax

tengo un problema en parte logico y en parte tecnico: tengo las siguientes tablas:

`ingreso_materials`

| id | fecha | user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13-03-2021 | 1 |

`det_ingreso_materials`

| id | material_id | cantidad | producto | ingreso_material_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 20 | Modem | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 50 | Conectores | 1 |

`transferencia_bodegas`

| id | fecha_transferencia | user | detalle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13-03-2021 | 1 | 10 modems a valpo |

`det_transferencia_bodegas`

| id | transferencia_bodega_id | cantidad | material_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 5 |

El usuario puede ingresar uno o varios materiales a una bodega (insert a tablas `ingreso_materials` y `det_ingreso_materials`) y luego puede transferir materiales desde una bodega a otra (insert a tablas `transferencia_bodegas` y `det_transferencia_bodegas`).

En un formulario tengo un select para seleccionar una bodega y depende esta selección se llena un select con los materiales disponibles para transferir.

El problema es que actualmente los insert los hace bien, pero no encuentro la forma de que el/los materiales que se transfirieron aparezcan en el select de los materiales disponibles, es decir si en mi *Bodega 1* tengo *modems* y *conectores* y desde mi *Bodega 2* transferí *routers* cuando vuelva a transferir materiales desde la *Bodega 1* tenga *modems, conectores* y *routers* (que se transfirieron anteriormente).

En mi controlador tengo esta query (que me muestra los materiales disponibles segun el `id` de la *bodega*) y (aquí debería tambien incluir los materiales que hayan sido transferidos).

```
public function getBodegas($id){
        //$materiales = Bodega::find($id)->material;
        $materiales = DB::table('materials as m')
        ->join('det_ingreso_materials as d', 'm.id', 'd.material_id')
        ->join('bodegas as b', 'b.id', 'd.bodega_id')
        ->select('b.nombre_bodega', 'b.id as bodega_id',
        'm.nombre_producto', 'm.id as material_id',
        'd.id as det_ingreso_material_id', 'd.cantidad')
        ->where('b.id',$id)
        ->get();

        return response()->json(['data' => $materiales], 200);
    }
```

Estoy probando con esta query, pero no trae ningun resultado y no se si sera posible hacer algo como lo planteado...

```
select 
b.nombre_bodega,
m.nombre_producto, m.id as material_id,
d.id, d.cantidad, dtb.id
from 
materials as m
inner join det_ingreso_materials as d on d.material_id = m.id
inner join bodegas as b on b.id = d.bodega_id
inner join det_transferencia_bodegas as dtb on dtb.det_ingreso_material_id = d.id
where b.id= 2
```

Saludos cordiales

Comment: Que almacena la variable materiales antes de que la uses en el join ?

Comment: Hola @BetaM, esa variable deberia traerme toda la info de la tabla Materials

Comment: ¿Y por que a una variable que ya tiene el resultado de una consulta le intentas luego asignar el valor de otra consulta?